# pthread_exit return value

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads, pthread-join

This is surprising for me.

```
static int ret = 50;
void * thread_func(void *arg)
{
    pthread_exit(&ret);
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t thr;
    int *exit_status;
    pthread_create(&thr, NULL, thread_func, NULL);
    sleep(2);
    pthread_join(thr, (void **)&exit_status);
    printf("value of exit status - %d\n", *exit_status);

    ret = 20;
    pthread_join(thr, (void **)&exit_status);
    printf("value of exit status - %d\n", *exit_status);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
value of exit status - 50
value of exit status - 20
```

I was expecting both the times the exit_status would be the actual exit value(50 in my case) of the thread. Instead it is just returning the value of the global variable which I used for pthread_exit. Is it not a bug?

Comment: I'd say the 2nd call to `pthread_join()` provokes undefined behaviour, or at least fail. You might like to check the values returned by "system" calls. See the *Rationale Section* here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q**: What would you return if you wanted to specify how to get the *current* value of `ret`.

**A**: The address of `ret`.

**Q**: What do you return?

**A**: The address of `ret.

**Q**: So what does the caller get when they dereference it?

**A**: The current value of `ret`.

You probably want `pthread_exit(ret);` -- returning the *value* of `ret`, and corresponding changes in the code that calls `pthread_join`.